# WordPress Full Screen Gallery wordpress plugin - How to get next and previous buttons

Tags: wordpress, plugins, navigation, gallery, fullscreen

I've been looking for a solution to this for a very long time with no luck, hopefully someone here can help me out.

I am using a wordpress plugin called 'WordPress Full Screen Gallery', and i'm trying to put next and previous navigation buttons when the gallery is opened. The javascript code has the following:

```
// Jump to the next background in the current slideshow
    next: function() {
        var from = step;

        if ( step ) {
            $.vegas( 'slideshow', {
                step: step
            }, true );

            $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegasnext', [ $current.get(0), step - 1, from - 1 ] );
        }

        return $.vegas;
    },

    // Jump to the previous background in the current slideshow
    previous: function() {
        var from = step;

        if ( step ) {
            $.vegas( 'slideshow', {
                step: step - 2
            }, true );

            $( 'body' ).trigger( 'vegasprevious', [ $current.get(0), step - 1, from - 1 ] );
        }

        return $.vegas;
    },
```

I want to know how to add buttons with these functions that will take me to the next and previous slide.

I really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about that plugin, but if you know enough about wordpress you could just use a different jquery slider.  I just found this one on google.

Typically if you can't find how to add something in the documentation, then it can be a nightmare trying to figure it out.  But I could be wrong.  I just don't like re-inventing the wheel unless I absolutely have to.

http://manos.malihu.gr/simple-jquery-fullscreen-image-gallery